# Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream

Tags: magento-1.9

I still can't get to fix this error. I'm just trying to load a magento project in my local:

Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/box/app/Mage.php on line 51

All file are in the right place.

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Comment: Please give us more content to understand your problem. Thank you.

Comment: I have just cloned a magento project from Github and this is the error it shows. I have modifed the htaccess file but apparently is not working. What is curious is that I make a var dump to ROOT FOLDER and it shows the right folder.

Comment: Maybe is not calling the right folder? Any idea what could be happening here? Thanks!